# Htaccess https referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, uri, referrer

I have a question about apache redirection.

I have this in my htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://csirc\.ugr\.es
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ugr/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)        http://www.example.com/%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]
```

With that I make the url (referrer) to see my uri.

How can I do if the referrer is https, example.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_REFERER} !^http://csirc\.ugr\.es
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://csirc\.ugr\.es
```

The uri would be the same.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://csirc\.ugr\.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^ugr/ http://www.example.com/%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]
```

Comment: I am sorry.

I have commented everything except the lines that make me and does not work.

Should show xxxxxxxx.com/ugr and me appears www.example.com.

Comment: See updated rule but how are you testing it? `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is only populated when you click on a link.